# Send Query or SP output as HTML mail from Azure data factory

Tags: azure

I'm trying to implement Azure data factory pipeline. From there trying to execute one SP and need to send output in HTML format from Azure data factory through Logic App. Facing issue while sending output to Web task in ADF.
Any hint ?
Error details
Error code
2108
Troubleshooting guide
Failure type
User configuration issue
Details
{"error":{"code":"InvalidRequestContent","message":"The request content is not valid and could not be deserialized: 'Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: <. Path '', line 0, position 0.'."}}
Source

Answer (score 0):

In Body option of the Setting TAB in Web Activity, Instead of adding the JSON in the "Dynamic Content", add JSON as usual in the box.
Refer below screen shot:
[image]